# Should i use 4 xib in my tableview or use 4 different tableview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, tableview, swift4

I need one help regarding the selection between 1 tableview with 4 xib or using the 4 tableviews.

Currently, I have a UI, where 
1. Complete UI Need to be scrollable
2. Have headers and after each header a uiview (contents of this uiview are different, total 4 types of different view).

In one of these xib files, I have charts implemented too.

Should I use a single tableview and then add 4 xib files based on conditions or just use scrollview as the base and then keep on adding tableview.?

What should be parameter for deciding which one to implement?

Comment: Without seeing any designs, it sounds like you are describing a tableview with sections, a header for each section, and 4 unique tableviewCells. If it looks like a tableview I always use a tableview. It adds too much complexity to try duplicate something similar when theres an inbuilt control for it. Tableviews are easy to use and very modular, they can be easily changed later on if the UI is updated. I normally only use scrollviews for things like forms, where having textfields in separate cells makes it painful to extract and combine data

Answer (score 0):

User single tableview, based on conditions add xibs. This is the best approach.

1.You can add multple sections. based on sections you can insert different views accordingly 
 1. You can add multiple rows in every section.
 2. If you have minimal count of data to show. for example upto `5`. add xibs by checking `indexpath` in section.

```
//Example
if indexPath.section == 0 {
switch indexPath.row {
  case 1:
   //First custom tableview cell
  case 2:
   //Second custom tableview cell
  case 3:
   //Third custom tableview cell
}
}
```

**Edit**
Regarding to Dynamic cell height, In `viewDidload` add

```
yourTableview.rowHeight = someValue
yourTableview.estimatedRowHeight = someValue
```

//Height

````
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        case 1:
             return your desired height if you want 
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Okay, but I have implemented that using this approach, but facing the height problem. Height of cell is not adjusted. tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 120
        tableview.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension. I am using these and func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    } .    Its only if I add return some hard coded value (like return 200), only them i am able to see 4 cells